# Ubuntu 22.04.1 login error displaying I/O error

Tags: boot, grub2, login, startup, pagestack

My laptop was initially partitioned to contain both Windows and Linux, however the hard drive crashed. I bought a new hard drive and someone helped to install only Ubuntu 22.04 on it.

After pressing the power button it boots up, but it doesn't get to the login screen. After showing the GRUB menu, it displays some boot messages and then stops at a blank black screen with a static mouse cursor.

I tried to used recovery mode to make it login, but it still it did not get to the login page, and then I had to force poweroff by holding down the laptop's power button. It displayed the below error screen.

[image]

Comment: You have drive problems with your SDA device...  If you had prior drive problems as I understand it; your drive problems maybe a *symptom* of other problems (eg. *even good components fail if fed incorrect power*) thus I'd check your hardware.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools maybe helpful; but check your hardware!

Comment: FYI:   You mention using *power button* to shutdown; from what I can see & read, there is no reason for that. Instead of power off, command your system to shutdown (even if that's via SySrq commands; ie. look after your hardware as much as possible & only use power-buttons if you absolutely have to!)

Comment: I agree with @guiverc about drives showing bad symptoms when other issues are around.  Depending on your laptop you might have a bad data cable running to the drive.  Or if it is directly connected to the motherboard it can have a bad connector there.  I have a data server where drives on it used to show random errors here and there.  Turned out that the SATA cables on the drives were loosening up over time and showing I/O errors, etc.  I replaced all the cables with locking cables and they have been solid since.  The laptop may need to be fully diagnosed.